# Python the last for loop in my code is always ignored

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a handful of for loops currently to test various things, and for some reason whatever for loop is the last one in the code, it is always ignored. I can rearrange the loops however I like, but the last loop is always ignored. And I have no idea why. There are two more loops before the code snippet but they are what create docsplit.

docsplit is a list of words taken from a document:

```
for word in docsplit:
    if "http" in word or "HTTP" in word or "Http" in word:
        #if it isn't already in the list
        docsplit.remove(word)

for word in docsplit:
    if "@" in word:
        docsplit.remove(word)


for word in docsplit:
    if "+1" in word:
        docsplit.remove(word)
    #find any websites in docsplit

#remove any strings that have a regex like XXX-XXXX or XXX-XXXX-XXXX
for word in docsplit:
    if re.search(r'\d{3}-\d{4}', word):
        docsplit.remove(word)

#remove any strings that have a regex like (XXX)
for word in docsplit:
    if re.search(r"\(\d{3}\)", word):
        docsplit.remove(word)
```

Comment: Changing the sequence over which you are iterating is generally ill-advised.

Comment: It's possible there is no such pattern left in the list of strings. That's why it seems the last loop is not executed. Did you try adding some `print` statement inside the loop?

Comment: Don't ever modify an iterable whilst iterating over its contents. Better to iterate over a copy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), instead of changing the list while iterating over it (which is a bad practice):

```
import re
docsplit = ['http', '123-4567', 'foo']

docsplit = [word for word in docsplit if
            not ("http" in word or "HTTP" in word or "Http" in word)
            and not "@" in word
            and not "+1" in word
            and not re.search(r'\d{3}-\d{4}', word)
            and not re.search(r"\(\d{3}\)", word)
            ]

print(docsplit)
# ['foo']
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't even think about defining a variable with an IF statement.